# Angular : Update scope from factory not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory :

```
simuApp.factory('Incendie', function($http) {

    return {
        // liste des incendies
        incendies : [],

        // fonction pour récupérer la liste des incendies
        getListeIncendies : function() {

            $http.get(site_url+'gestionnaireFeu/listeIncendies').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // si liste retournée, on enregistre
                incendies = data;
                return data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Un problème est survenu. (service incendie : getListeIncendies).");
            });
        },

        // fonction pour supprimer un incendie donné
        supprimerIncendie : function(IDIncendie) {
            $http.get(site_url+'gestionnaireFeu/supprimerIncendie/'+IDIncendie).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // si liste retournée, on enregistre
                this.incendies = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Un problème est survenu. (service incendie : supprimerIncendie).");
            });
        },

        // fonction pour ajouter un incendie
        ajouterIncendie : function(newIDIncendie) {
            $http.get(site_url+'gestionnaireFeu/creerIncendie/'+newIDIncendie).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // si liste retournée, on enregistre
                incendies = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Un problème est survenu. (service incendie : ajouterIncendie).");
            });
        }
    }

});
```

And also a controller :

```
simuApp.controller('incendieController', function($scope, $http, Incendie) {

    // liaison du scope avec le service incendie
    //$scope.incendies         = Incendie.incendies;

    $scope.incendies         = Incendie.getListeIncendies();

    $scope.updateIncendies = function() {
        $scope.incendies = Incendie.getListeIncendies();
    }

    // $scope.getListeIncendies = Incendie.getListeIncendies();
    // $scope.ajouterIncendie   = Incendie.ajouterIncendie();
    // $scope.supprimerIncendie = Incendie.supprimerIncendie();

});
```

My view is not updated and still, the ajax call is ok. (checked with firebug, i have the json returned).

Here's the code of my view :

```
<div ng-controller="incendieController">
    TEST
    <div ng-repeat="incendie in incendies">
        incendies : {{ incendie.idFeu }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't have any error but my view only display "TEST".

Do you have any idea why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return from an AJAX call, it async! Instead, `return` the actual `$http` request and use `.then` and assign your data in the controller

```
getListeIncendies : function() {
    return $http.get(site_url+'gestionnaireFeu/listeIncendies').then(function(result) {
        // si liste retournée, on enregistre
        return result.data;
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Un problème est survenu. (service incendie : getListeIncendies).");
    });
},
```

And your controller:

```
Incendie.getListeIncendies().then(function(data) {
    $scope.incendies = data;
});
```

Comment: Here, you are not assigning data to `incendies` list.

Comment: @levi -- Im not assigning to the `incendies` in the factory because there's no need for it.

Comment: OP wants to assign it, may be if he wants to use factory on another controller, he wouldn't need to fetch the list again.

Comment: @tymeJV thx, it worked perfectly ! I never heard about then, can you explain a bit please ?

Comment: @Maxime -- Here's a nice article with great explanations: http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/

Answer (score 1):

your `getListeIncendies` should looks like this:

```
getListeIncendies : function() {
    var scope = this;
    return $http.get(site_url+'gestionnaireFeu/listeIncendies').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // si liste retournée, on enregistre
        scope.incendies = data;
        return scope.incendies;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Un problème est survenu. (service incendie : getListeIncendies).");
    });
},
```

Note `var scope = this;` and `scope.incendies = data;`
Then in your controller

```
Incendie.getListeIncendies().then(function(response) {
    $scope.incendies = response;
});
```

Comment: You can't `return` from an AJAX call like that... and factories dont have access to the `scope`

Comment: @levi thx but your solution didn't work for me. TymeJV's solution worked well, thx anyway :)

Comment: @Maxime the mine is almost equal to tymeJV, but is ok :)